# How can i find which all MATLAB files have been executed during a simulation?

Tags: matlab, simulation

I am running a MATLAB simulation. It starts from a file `top_file.m` and it calls some other `.m` files and this may indeed calls other `.m` files like that.

Is there a way that I can know which all files were executed during the simulation, and if possible the order in which they were executed?

Comment: You can run the profiler tool from within the menu, that lists all functions your program uses, including execution time.

Comment: Daiiiii duplicate neelakandan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed by [Adriaan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538000/how-can-i-find-which-all-matlab-files-have-been-executed#comment54857021_33538000) Matlab's [`profiler`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) tool does exactly what you want and *much more*!

You can run it from command line:

```
>> profile clear; profile on; %// clear history and start the tool
>> top_file; %// run your code
>> profile off; %// switch off the tool
>> profile viewer; %// launch GUI to view results
```

In the profiler's GUI you'll see the functions that were called, and their run time.

Try it! It is a very useful tool.

Answer (score 6):

There is a built-in function [`matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.codetools.requiredfilesandproducts.html) since R2014a which will return a list of the dependencies of any file without having to execute it.

```
>> files = matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts('test.m')
files = 
    '/path/to/test.m'
    '/path/to/test.m/dependencies'
```

Comment: That's much better! I was hesitant in recommending `profiler`, since it eats away on your resources like crazy.

Comment: You should mention which vsns of MATLAB have this tool.  AFAIK  R2012 does not, for example. (No, I can't upgrade per corporate edict)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Added. It's also stated at the bottom of the documentation page I linked to.